# How do I write the response.data from an API call from Kudoshub to a Zip file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently writing an application and API routes in NodeJS/Express and attempting to integrate it with Kudoshub's API. The end vision for the route at this stage would be an automated pipeline uploading a CSV from where our Node client exists through Kudoshub's API, retrieving results when done. I'm able to upload the files using axios; however, I'm running into issues when trying to download them. I recieve a response in reponse.data, but when I write this response to a file it is corrupted/inaccessible.

The Kudoshub endpoint is as follows:

```
Endpoint – GET
https://leads.kudoshub.com/api/download-all-results?file_uid=<File Uid>&api_key=<API Key>

Response –
{
 "processed": <Processed Count>,
 "progress": <Progress In Percent>,
 "userFileStatus": <File Current Status>,
 "status": "Success"
}
*File Uid - Get from the response of upload-and-validate API
*Note - It will return Zip file which contains all processed files when completed. i.e. when progress = 100%
```

My sample attempt is below as well:

```
router.route('/download')
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        var api_key = "";
        const url = "https://leads.kudoshub.com/api/download-all-results?file_uid=cdjn9popg4b6r&api_key=";
        
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                const buf1 = Buffer.from(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
                fs.writeFileSync(`response.zip`, response.data)
                fs.writeFile('filename.zip', buf1, (err) => {
                    console.log(err ? 'Error: '+err : 'File saved');
                  });
                // res.json({ data: ["running"] });


            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                res.json({ data: [] });

            });
    });
```

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Note - It will return Zip file which contains all processed files when completed. i.e. when progress = 100` - did you check if progress = 100?

Comment: Yes the file I'm trying to download for testing right now has been complete for several days. The request works in postman. I just can't seem to figure out anything that works in NodeJS/Express